# Cookie created on server not stored on client

Tags: http, cookies, browser

Given this server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Mar 2018 12:17:57 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8888
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: key=value;Version=1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 276
```

I thought this cookie (*key=value*) would be stored on client side and I would be able to view it from Chrome DevTools. However I don't see any cookie there. And the cookie is not included on the further requests made after the requested shown above. So I guess it's not stored.

To store the cookies is not the default behavior of the browser?

I've tried setting the cookie property `httpOnly` to true with the same results.

How can force the browser to store the cookie without using JS and including it on further requests without any JS interaction?